# Whether plist file decrease performance in iphone?

Tags: objective-c

I have tabbar application, every tabs having viewcontroller, am getting the values from plist file in viewwillappear in each view controller. whether it will decrease performance of the application, please suggest which one is the best

Answer (score 0):

Are you noticing any lag in the performance of your app? If so, have you profiled your app to ensure that loading the configuration from a plist file is the issue? If not, it might decrease performance a bit, but it is fast enough.

Do not optimize code that does not need to be optimized.